# How to receive Long data with more than 18 digits transmitted by back-end engineers? Is the front-end or the back-end responsible for this?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, request, frontend

The thing is, the data passed to me by our **back-end engineer** has a **Long** type data with more than **18 digits**.

I told him that the last two digits of this data will become 00 after converting to JS.

I asked him  to transmit the **String** type to me, or shorten the length of the **Long**, but he was unwilling.

He told me that there are many ways to solve this problem in the **front end**, such as **BigInt** or other ways.

What I want to ask is, in the architecture of a project, who should be responsible for this data? **Front-end engineer** or **back-end engineer**? What is the best way to deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I can't say if there's really a single source responsible. The small differences in languages and their data structures make this question difficult- JSON with web servers being a perfect example.

I think this is a responsibility of both parties to find the best conclusion. I think the most important question to ask would be: "Is it possible for the number have less digits?" and if the answer is no, for precision or whatever reason, it's on the front end engineer. It's on the backend engineer, however, to ensure they know what is absolutely necessary before simply throwing a new problem to solve at the frontend.

Comment: Yes, I have the same opinion as you. And I suggest that the backend process the data like this, maybe he doesn't want to listen to grandpa, and still let me do the processing on the front end :(